# tensorflow estimator LinearRegressor: why is my loss so big

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I used LinearRegressor from tensorflow estimator library (tf.estimator.LinearRegressor) for my tensorflow model training, evaluation and then prediction. However, the evaluation always showed a very big loss value; therefore, the predictions were totally inaccurate.

Here are how I defined the train, evaluation, prediction input functions and the LinearRegressor:

```
def train_input_fn(x, y):
    training_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = x,
        y = y,
        batch_size = 32,
        shuffle = True,
        num_epochs = None
    )
    return training_input_fn

def eval_input_fn(x, y):
    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = x,
        y = y,
        batch_size = 32,
        shuffle = False,
        num_epochs = 1
    )
    return eval_input_fn

def predict_input_fn(x):
    predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = x,
        shuffle = False,
        num_epochs = 1 
    )
    return predict_input_fn

def get_linear_regressor():
    properties = load_data()
    del properties['_id']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = split_data(properties)
    linear_regressor = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=build_features(),
                                                    model_dir = "linear_regressor")
    linear_regressor.train(input_fn = train_input_fn(X_train, y_train), steps=5000)

    loss = linear_regressor.evaluate(input_fn = eval_input_fn(X_test, y_test))
    print("Loss is: " + str(loss))
    return linear_regressor
```

Result:

> Loss is: {'average_loss': 417497550000.0, 'label/mean': 751504.7,
>   'loss': 13186813000000.0, 'prediction/mean': 331845.62, 'global_step':
>   145000}

I had 6472 data points which were split for training and evaluation with 8:2 ratio.

What have I done incorrectly? How can I improve the accuracy of prediction?

Comment: What about your data? It's impossible to help you without knowing from what distribution your data come from.

Comment: My data, housing price, comes from a reliable third-party API which has 6 features: number of bedrooms , number of bathrooms, number of parking slot, distance to city center, property type and postal code. The target feature is price.

Comment: Well, linear regressor might not be a good choice for this problem. Especially, it won't work well with features like a distance to city centre property type and postal code. You should look into models like decision trees or random forests.

Comment: Thanks. Why won't it work with well with features like distance to city, property type and postal code? Even that is the case, I would expect the loss is not so high and the predictions shouldn't be so far off from the reasonable ranges. I have tried to remove those features from the model, but the loss becomes even higher.

Comment: That's because a linear model basically assigns a weight `w_i` to each feature `f_i` and approximates the target as a weighted sum of `w_i*f_i` plus an optional bias weight to minimise average loss (usually msre). Clearly, your target doesn't depend linearly on any of the features, especially on those I mentioned, that is, there're no suitable weights to fit your target price accurately.